# Input on a cipher?

Tags: cipher

So, I randomly stumbled across this cipher/code and I am pretty stuck and wondering if anyone had any input:

65706377 736D 797367 676B72687A67 74636D64 7161 B8B 78863B1F56468 767A796B 71 6C6E79657A 657771 73766C 6466 62676E676271 64717364 7770712E 1CE01966 6369696D 7769677077 7572 7069676D2E 6E6177 79746A 7970676167766F 6C79627A2E 19E0196D72 61626274 6E6662 63757061 686F73717178 185E19601975 6C787872 6B686B 6F797A6A2E

So far I can tell that the 60-7A represents ASCII values but after converting them not everything adds up:

Epcw sm ysg gkrhzg tcmd qa B8B 78863B1F56468 vzyk q lnyez ewq svl df bgngbq dqsd wpq. 1CE01966 ciim wigpw ur pigm. Naw ytj ypgagvo lybz. 19E0196D72 abbt nfb cupa hosqqx 185E19601975 lxxr khk oyzj.

The parts that I just left as numbers are the parts that don't convert to a-z values.

I keep trying to solve the parts that I have but can't come to any sort of solution. Does anyone have any input?

Comment: Can you tell us where you found it?

Comment: Yeah, sorry, you need to say exactly where it's from if it's not a puzzle you made yourself. My apologies for the fact that the boilerplate message says "off-topic"; of course this isn't off-topic at all, it's just that all the close-reasons have to be shoehorned into a small set of messages. Once we've got suitable attribution in the question, it should be able to be reopened.